# Google Forms/ Sheets

Tags: google-forms

I want have students submit the same Google Form every time they use their pedometer or Fitbit. Then I want the sheet to sum the students steps each time a form is submitted. I don’t want to manually scan through 500 responses and add each student individually. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? [image]

Comment: Welcome. Do you have a test sheet?

Comment: I essentially want to add the totals by email address. I tried SUMIF but would have to put all 500 email in. Is there a way around that?

Comment: In that case my provided formula meets your needs. All you have to do is adjust the ranges. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into consideration the little info you give, I imagine that if your response sheet (`Form Responses`) looks something like this:

```
+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+-------+
|      Timestamp      | Last name | First name |           Email           | Steps |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+-------+
| 2020-10-19 23:25:51 | Boc       | Florencia  | fboc9@vinaora.com         |   356 |
| 2020-10-19 22:33:29 | Boc       | Florencia  | fboc9@vinaora.com         |   175 |
| 2020-10-19 19:58:08 | Splevins  | Donny      | dsplevins7@ucla.edu       |   153 |
| 2020-10-19 18:40:52 | Castagne  | Cedric     | ccastagneb@ow.ly          |   382 |
| 2020-10-19 17:56:40 | Gipp      | Eloisa     | egipp4@webmd.com          |   147 |
| 2020-10-19 17:26:39 | Splevins  | Donny      | dsplevins7@ucla.edu       |   365 |
| 2020-10-19 17:09:17 | Riccardi  | Monica     | mriccardi6@wikispaces.com |   289 |
| 2020-10-19 17:07:08 | Boc       | Florencia  | fboc9@vinaora.com         |   284 |
| 2020-10-19 16:54:45 | Gipp      | Eloisa     | egipp4@webmd.com          |   174 |
| 2020-10-19 14:20:50 | Riccardi  | Monica     | mriccardi6@wikispaces.com |   233 |
| 2020-10-19 14:02:00 | Splevins  | Donny      | dsplevins7@ucla.edu       |   173 |
| 2020-10-19 09:51:38 | Riccardi  | Monica     | mriccardi6@wikispaces.com |   177 |
| 2020-10-19 04:49:03 | Splevins  | Donny      | dsplevins7@ucla.edu       |   320 |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------------------+-------+
```

If so, you then need to create a new sheet and place the following [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) formula i cell `A1`

```
=QUERY('Form Responses'!A1:E, 
    "select B, C, sum(E) where A is not null group by B, C ",1)
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

*If still in need please let us know.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. :)